Email Tracker using NodeJs ; outlook adds the src in blockedurl tag of img
I am writing code to track whether the email sent via nodemailer was open or not by the receiver.
The problem is ; on the recivers inbox the transperent image becomes :
img data-imagetype="External" blockedimagesrc="http://localhost:9000/image/yash@yash.com"
in outlook.
and
img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/meips/ADKq_NZRQf_zJk_6iin4Q_w2g05bKs3Afmwo02D6E2pVoHzKUBuuflvmtkArQ1x49gtqTPdfw8e27sjuMVcGJkG-kA=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:9000/image/yash@yash.com" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit" jslog="138226; u014N:xr6bB; 53:WzAsMl0."
in gmail.
Hence: my endpoint which is on http://localhost:9000/image/yash@yash.com doesnot get called.
What should i do?
I have tried https, also replacing localhost with my own private ip address
